# Backstack Issue in fragment and activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, back-stack, fragment-backstack, fragmentmanager

Suppose I have total  7 activity say A, B, C, D, E, F, G, in Activity  A I have 4 fragments after clicking on 4th fragment I am launching Activity B, Then Activity C, D, E, F .after Coming to Activity F, I want to navigate to 2 fragments of  Activity A but I want to clear all backstack  till 2nd fragment of activity A, after clicking on back button 1st fragment of Activity A will display as I am adding all fragment  to backstack how will I solve this problem. please help me

code for calling 2nd fragment in Activity F

```
SeconFragment fragment = new SeconFragment();
            addFragmentToActivity(getFragmentManager(), fragment, R.id.fragment_container_top,"secondfagment");

  public void addFragmentToActivity(@NonNull FragmentManager fragmentManager,
                                             @NonNull Fragment fragment, int frameId,String backstacklabel) {
        FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(frameId, fragment,backstacklabel);
        transaction.commit();
    }
```

Comment: post your code where you are calling activity 2nd fragment

Comment: @quicklearnerI  I update  code in question.please check

Comment: @AkshayPadalkar check the answer below

Answer (score 0):

Your question is bit confusing, but here is what is got

```
FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
for(int i = 0; i < fm.getBackStackEntryCount(); ++i) {  
    Fragment SecondFrag= fm .findFragmentByTag("yourFragmentTag");
     if(SecondFrag !=null){
        return;
       }
     else{
     fm.popBackStack();
    }
}
```

In code `fm .findFragmentByTag("yourFragmentTag")` **yourFragmentTag** replace with your fragmentTag which you dont want to remove from `backstack`

Hope this solves your problem

Comment: I try this but   fm .findFragmentByTag("yourFragmentTag") always gives me null.i  checked fm.getFragments() which gives me  list of last active fragment not backstack  fragments list.

Answer (score 0):

Use Intent flag `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` to start your start Activity A, then check if first and second fragment instances are still alive. If not relaunch your fragments in order with `AddToBackStack()`

```
Fragment frag = fm.findFragmentByTag("fragmentTag");
  if(frag!=null){
     loadFragments(); // code to launch fragments.
    }
  else{
  fm.popBackStack();
}
```